# Как сделать раздвижение вбока блоков при прокрутке страницы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть обычный сайт. В первом экране над самим контентом расположено 2 блока (50% по ширине и 100% по высоте) с фиксированным позиционированием. Левый (top: 0; left: 0;) и правый (top: 0; right: 0). Как сделать следующий эффект? При прокрутке страницы как колесиком мыши, так и полосой прокрутки, и клавиатурой левый фиксированный блок уезжает влево, правый - вправо. Как только блоки заехали за область просмотра, прокрутка начинает работать в штатном режиме, и скроллится сайт?

Comment: кстати, интересный вопрос - как понять, что происходит скрол, если на самом деле скрола не происходит :)

Comment: более ста примеров со скроллом в джейкваери [сссылка](http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-animate-scroll-effects/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваше решение есть отдельным аддоном/фунцией, а также еще доп. функции:  http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/ Как раз на сайте и примеры и сами скроллеры(можно даже добавить еще).